# jQuery UI Datepicker Causes Internet Explorer to Crash

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm experiencing an issue where jQuery UI's Datepicker is causing Internet Explorer (versions 8 and 9, maybe others) to sometimes (but not always) crash. IE crashes about 25% of the time on page load or after fiddling with a datepicker field. This may or may not be particular to Windows 7. I can reproduce the problem using various different versions of jQuery from 1.6.2 to 1.7.1.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLW8D/

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#someDate').datepicker();
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="someDate" id="someDate" value="">
```

I can get IE to crash fairly easily by navigating to the jsfiddle page and then start playing around (refresh, pick a date, tab out of the field, etc.).

When IE crashes, a dialog is displayed: "Internet Explorer has stopped working - A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available." The event log shows an application error with event ID 1000.

Any suggestions?

~~~~~~~~~

UPDATE: This did get resolved, but I'm hesitant to mark it as answered or provide a real answer because I don't understand what was changed to make it work. All the occurrences of the problem were happening on a VM that was distributed by the IT staff. The IT staff changed something on the VM (presumably a Windows setting, maybe?) and the issue was resolved.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your machine. I can view the jsFiddle and click the field - and while the datepicker is not styled, it still shows up and reacts to events appropriately. I requested it 8 times in IE9, and never had a crash.

Comment: It's not unique to my machine. It's happening on all the machines I've checked in the office. So far, all Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Once it happened to me. On different machines with IE8 on Windows XP, and using jQuery 1.6.x (i don't remember which version i was using) but it crashed every time (I even used jQuery file from Google CDN). Then I changed of version (1.7) and it worked without problem. Try using different version of jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: I'm getting this same problem in the latest version of IE 11 - jQuery 1.10.2, jQuery UI 1.10.3.  I'm not using any special initialization, just $("#ChooseDate").datepicker();  I get the same error that happens randomly to everyone using IE (all versions) that I have deployed this application to.

Answer (score 0):

If I do something similar when initializing DatePicker elements which was suggested by somebody on the internet:

```
$('.DatePicker').datepicker({
  onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
     var now = new Date(this.value);
     if (now) {
        var max = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        var day = now.getDate() > max ? max : now.getDate();
        var newDate = new Date(year, month-1, day);
        inst.input.datepicker('setDate', newDate);
     }
  }
});
```

(Of course I have attached class=DatePicker at the required input elements.)

then IE always crashes when changing date.

if I ommit onChangeMonthYear handler or just comment out the inst.input.datepicker ... line, the problem disappears (of course in this case the required funcionality also disappears).

So I did some more experiments and realized that the problem is at the first line:

```
var now = new Date(this.value);
```

Here we try to construct a Date variable from the input field value. It looks that IE does not construct when the format is localized (like at me hungarian), so the result will be NaN. It looks this is the real problem. Anyhow it was strange for me that Chrome and Firefox worked properly.

So I have changed my first line into:

```
var now = inst.input.datepicker('getDate');
```

And there is no crash anymore.

I have found another strange behaviour at the bottom line: a small rectangle was visible for the DatePicker. This caused some mistakes as well when mouse over. But I have found a solution also for this adding a small piece of css after jquery.ui.css in my main template:

```
#ui-datepicker-div
{
    display: none;
}
```

So I am happy it works in IE6, Chrome, Firefox as I wanted.

Here is my final initialization code for datepicker:

```
$('.DatePicker').datepicker({
  onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
    var now = inst.input.datepicker('getDate');
    if (now) {
      var max = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      var day = now.getDate() > max ? max : now.getDate();
      var newDate = new Date(year, month-1, day);
      inst.input.datepicker('setDate', newDate);
    }
  }
});
```

and my datetimepicker as well:

```
$('.DateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
  onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
    var now = inst.input.datepicker('getDate');
    if (now) {
      var max = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      var day = now.getDate() > max ? max : now.getDate();
      var newDate = new Date(year, month-1, day,
          now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
      inst.input.datepicker('setDate', newDate);
    }
  }      
});
```

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and jquery.ui.1.8.16

Miklos